# update git repository with apple script

Tags: git, applescript

I want to update my git Bitbucket online storage with apple script. This is the code that works in Terminal, but not when i run apple script.

```
cd /Users/mainuser/Desktop/Projects git add -A
git commit -m fromAppleScript
git push
```

crafted into apple script:

```
        say "updating backup"
        do shell script "cd /Users/mainuser/Desktop/Projects git add -A"
        do shell script "cd /Users/mainuser/Desktop/Projects git commit -m fromAppleScript"
        do shell script "cd /Users/mainuser/Desktop/Projects git push"
```

I am a bit puzzled why this code doesn't work. Can you help me out with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do shell script "cd /Users/mainuser/Desktop/Projects && git add -A && git commit -m fromAppleScript && git push"
```

Comment: I ended up using ; between commands. I like your I liner way even more.

Comment: Chaining commands with the `&&` operator has the benefit that if the first command fails, the second command is skipped too. Semi-colons just act as command separators, as do line feeds; they don't affect execution, so even if a vital command like the `cd` fails the subsequent commands are still applied, but now in the wrong directory. Another option is to put `set -e` at the start of the script, which tells bash to exit immediately if _any_ subsequent command fails. Unix shells are notoriously fast and loose with teensy details like safety and reliability so it's best to code defensively.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue you're having is with the `cd` command preceding your `git add` and `git commit` commands. You're chaining two commands together.